# The saved video is not shown in the system gallery app

Tags: android, video, gallery, google-photos, android-mediascanner

After creating video and save it, I'm trying to make it visible in the gallery app by scanning the video path using the code below :

Path of saved video :

```
 public String getPath() {
        String videoFileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
        File storageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                        + "/MyFolderApp");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            success = storageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            File videoFile = new File(storageDir, videoFileName);
            savedVideoPath = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        return savedVideoPath;
    }
```

Scan path :

```
  private void galleryScanner(String path) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(path);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

After saving the video, I call the scan method like this: `galleryAddPic(getPath());`

**Weird behavior :** If I open the **Google Photos** app and go to **Album > MyFolderApp**, I could see the saved video there, also when I exit the Google Photos app and return to Gallery System, the saved video shown normally

Comment: `String videoFileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";` - this looks especially suspect. Have you verified this file exists?

Comment: @PPartisan thank you for your comment, yes after going to **Google Photos**, I could see the saved video with _videoFileName_ as the name of it

Comment: I mean in your code - call `exists()` on `new File(storageDir, videoFileName);` and log out the result. I suspect you're using the wrong file name for your video.

Comment: after doing this :   `if (videoFile .exists())
                Log.d("FILE", "I'M EXISTS");
            else
                Log.d("FILE", "I'M NOT EXISTS");` 
I get this  **I'M NOT EXISTS**  in log

Comment: So you don't have the correct filename. Instead of using `String videoFileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";`, get the filename for your file wherever you create it, and pass it to your method.

Comment: @PPartisan , But why when I check the video name in Google Photos, I find the exact name, I give it, I mean I find for example **20190821123345.mp4**

Comment: Have you printed the value of `videoFileName` to logcat to verify it's what you expect?